# Is it possible to modify failure conditions for already started scenario?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-4

We are playing custom scenario made by someone else in multiplayer hot-seat mode. After investing significant time into this game we found out that it has some weird failure conditions. Our save file is right before the game over for one of the players: player-1 ends his turn, player-2 loses.

Is is possible to modify this scenario vie editor to disable this custom failure condition? Or may be we can do something with our save file? Or some cheats exist? Any solution will work, we just want to continue this game like it has traditional "lose all towns and heroes" losing condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it in the past, and it didn't work: you will sadly need to start your game over. Once the scenario has been started, there is no known and easy way to modify the save.

Theoretically, you could use a HEX editor, but you would probably be the first person to ever try this.

Comment: yes, I made this conclusion too. Had to abandon that game sadly